# How to play microphone audio through non default output speaker in MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudioengine

I want to listen to the microphone audio through an output device which is not set as default device in system preference in MacOS.

Ex: In system preference default output device is *Macbook pro speaker* but I want to listen to the audio through *External Headphones*.

With the below implementation I can play listen to microphone through the default output device of macos.

```
    private func resetAudioEngine() {
        if let audioEngine = audioEngine {
            audioEngine.stop()
            self.audioEngine = nil
        }
        
        let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)
        audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.mainMixerNode, to: outputNode, format: nil)
        self.audioEngine = audioEngine
    }
```

I also tried the below code block as well. Still audio plays through default output device. I don't want to change default output device from my app.

```
var outputDeviceID = deviceid
if let audioSetup  = audioEngine.outputNode.audioUnit {
            AudioUnitSetProperty(audioSetup,kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice,kAudioUnitScope_Global,AudioUnitElement(0),
                                          &outputDeviceID, UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: outputDeviceID)))
        }
```